# How to exclude series from displaying in the matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a loop going through a big dataset storing the data in various lists and plotting them at the end. However, some of the series are only contain `Null` values and don't want them to include in the legend. Is there any way I can exclude series from a legend? This is a simple example that `z` contains only `Null`s.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1, 5)
y = 1/x
z = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]

plt.plot(x,y, label = 'x data')
plt.plot(x,z, label = 'z data')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just put the plot command in an if, checking whether the series contains null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a function that returns the label with a preceding underscore if any values are NaN in the array:

```
def label_not_nan(arr, label):
    if np.isnan(arr).any():
        return f'_{label}'
    return label

plt.plot(x, y, label=label_not_nan(x, 'x data'))
plt.plot(x, z, label=label_not_nan(z, 'z data'))
```

Labels starting with an underscore are not displayed in the legend, as pointed out in the comments.

**Note:** a previous solution had the function return None instead of preceding underscore. That solution seems to no longer work.

Comment: That's a good simple solution for lists with containing `nan`s, but my all lists contain `nan`s - so I only want the lists which completely contain `nan`s. So if `k` = [5,np.nan, 3, np.nan] `k` still needs to be displayed in legend. Thanks

Comment: Change np.isnan(arr).any() to np.isnan(arr).all()

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. According to matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html):

*Specific lines can be excluded from the automatic legend element selection by defining a label starting with an underscore.*

So changing the function to return `'_'` instead of `None` will work.

Comment: @eindzl, at first I thought this was due to this answer being old, but it appears that the underscore behavior exists for at least 7 years. Moreover, probably None was supported in previous versions (I tested it at the time) but no longer is. Thanks, updating the answer.